# Font not working when printing pdf the first time

Tags: jquery, html, pdf-generation, font-face

This is the font I use on the style I use for printing:

```
@font-face{
    font-family:"DejaVu Sans";src:url(kendo/fonts/DejaVu/DejaVuSans.ttf?v=1.1) format("truetype")

}
body {
    font-family: "DejaVu Serif" , Arial;
    /*line-height: 1.428571429;*/
        line-height: 1.95em;
    color: #333333;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

When printing the first time the text does not appear. The second time it works ok with the desired font. Is there a way to make it work since the first time?

Comment: maybe I am wrong but,when using PDF printing, users might find that the fonts on the printed output are not what they expected. As PDF printing relies on a combination of Windows printer drivers (when printing from Windows applications), Ghostscript and a PDF viewer to deliver its output, you might have to experiment with the font settings for each of these components to see if this produces a better result.

Comment: another thing, are you generating the pdf yourself or it is random, means it is uploaded by user?

Comment: oh, I didnt know that. Haven tried.Well I have page in which users can click a "export to pdf" button, and all that is within a div will be shown as a pdf.